# MongoDB: deleting an array value in multiple documents in one collection using pymongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, pymongo

Afternoon all.  I hope you can help with a problem.  I am using creating a Flask app and using pymongo and I need to delete a singular array value from multiple arrays across many documents within one collection.  I have recipe documents within a 'recipes' collection, and within each of them is an array ('category') that can be between 1 and 3 values in length.  I have a feature available within the admin section of my site that allows for the deletion of a category from the 'categories' collection and so, to go with that, I want to delete any instances of that category value within the 'category' array on any recipe document within the recipes 'collection'.

I have managed to do this on a single document:

```
mongo.db.recipes.update(
        {"_id": ObjectId("60df2eec9df14e58d0c698c8")},
        {"$pull": {"category": category_id}}
    )
```

but have not managed this on the collection as a whole I have determined I need to use the $all with the $pull operator on the collection using the 'update_many' query and have so far tried:

```
mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"category": {"$all": {"$pull": {"category": category_id}}}})

mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"$all": {"$pull": {"category": category_id}}})

mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"category": {"$pullAll": {"category": category_id}}})
```

None of them work.  I keep getting a the error:

```
TypeError: update_many() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read - https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update_many#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many

1st parameter is filter which will be `{}` if you want to update all document

```
mongo.db.recipes.update_many(
  {} // filter filter,
  {} // update
)
```

---

```
mongo.db.recipes.update_many({ }, {"$pull": {"category": category_id}})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Tushar, I have tried this as:
`mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"$filter": {input: "category"}}, {"$all": {"$pull": {"category": category_id}}})`

and no luck - what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: do you have documents with key `input` ?

Comment: The key for the array is 'category' which can have up to three values.  I have tried what you suggested and get the error
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Unknown modifier: $all. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 9, 'errmsg': 'Unknown modifier: $all. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array'}

Comment: So I have tried:
1) mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"input": "category"}, {"$pull": {"category": category_id}})

Comment: 2) mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"input": "category"}, {"$pull": {"$all": {"category": category_id}}})

Comment: 3) mongo.db.recipes.update_many({"input": "category"}, {"$pullAll": {"category": [category_id]}})

Comment: None of these generate any errors but no values are deleted from the arrays on any documents.

Comment: Did not work- got the same error: Unknown modifier: $all. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 9, 'errmsg': 'Unknown modifier: $all. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array'}

Comment: just tried this: 
mongo.db.recipes.update_many({ }, {"$pull": {"category": category_id}})
and it worked by the looks of things!

Comment: This should worl `mongo.db.recipes.update_many({ }, {"$pull": {"category": category_id}})`